# Fetch the data from my MySQL database for the current month

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the data from my MySQL database for the current month.

In the database, I have a column `next_due` which stores the next month date.

Now, if suppose this column is `13-Nov-2020`, and today is 13-Nov-2020, code should show the data of those person whose due is on 13-Nov-2020.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM new_regis WHERE MONTH(next_due) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(next_due) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

But this is not working.

Comment: using a real timestamp column with a properly formatted timestamp would likely make this simpler.

Comment: Are your dates actually in that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should store dates in columns of type `DATE`. This would make your life a lot simpler.

Fortunately, MySQL has built-in functions to help you work with dates that are stored as text. `MONTH(next_due)` won't work, because MySQL doesn't know how to parse `next_due` as a date value. You'll have to tell it how first: `MONTH( STR_TO_DATE(next_due, '%d-%b-%Y') )`.

The [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function will parse a string into a date, given a format specifier of how to parse the string. That `%d-%b-%Y` format specifier should match your format if your days are two digits. If you store dates as `5-Nov-2020` (with a single digit for the day) use `%e` instead of `%d`. The full list of options for your format are listed with the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in the documentation.

So the following query should work for your purposes:

```
SELECT * FROM new_regis WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(next_due, '%d-%b-%Y')) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(next_due, '%d-%b-%Y')) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Comment: The question only needed guidance with `STR_TO_DATE()`. There are several pages where this advice exists on Stack Overflow.  Please help us to close redundant questions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to deal with Timestamp only in all the way.

- Store the next_due filed as timestamp.
- $today=time().
- Fetch from the database and compare.

```
$sql = "SELECT here";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
$next_due=$row['next_due'];
$today=time()
$data=array();
if ($next_due==$today)
{
//True show data here
$data['id']=$row['id'];
$data['name']=$row['name'];

print_r"$data";

}

else
{
//False
print"Sorry not current day.";
}

  }
}
 else {
  echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score -3):

To get current month data you can use

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(2020-05-15 17:36:38) = 5
```

Here 5 is the current month that you can get from PHP

Comment: Why minus vote! Minus vote just discourage to help

Comment: I suspect someone downvoted because the query won't work (quotes are missing) and also the person asking the question has a different date format this won't work for either. Compare your answer to the accepted one that clearly shows how to work with that format.

Comment: i was just give him an idea , and on the first he wrote: i want to fetch current month data. Quotation i did not use and is clearly visible, one developer can easily understand this.

Comment: @SKS you can choose to leave your answer here or remove it.  Either way, this redundant page is likely to be deleted entirely.